# Is there any python wrapper of google code which displays numerical values along with pie charts?

Tags: wxpython, pie-chart

All of the wrappers I have tried- pygooglecharts, pygocha- give labels, but do not list the exact percentages. Google charts lists the exact percentages. Any chance I can get them in Python, especially wxPython!